# Why does this don't work in visual studio 2012 (SP2)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, dereference

This should just replace the '*' by the word POINTER

```
#define POINTER *

// Define an 8bit byte
typedef unsigned short aByte;

// Define a pointer to an 8bit byte
typedef aByte POINTER aPointerToByte;
```

This will not compile in vs2012, but it did compile in vs2010

Comment: C or C++? I tagged it with C++. Feel free to change this to C if it is. The code can be either.

Comment: What exact error do you see?

Comment: Compiles just fine on VS2012.

Comment: The error that I get is error C2144: syntax error : 'unsigned short' should be preceded by ';'

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I am not sure I understand this, but somehow removing this block of code made the problem disappear.

```
#if !defined(__FreeBSD__)
   #include <pcrt32.h>
#endif
```